# Are there any advanced level math audiobooks?

Tags: reference-request, books

I am aware of a few interesting math podcasts but haven’t come across any interesting advanced math audiobook. Are there some?

Comment: I haven't come across any, but there should be. It reminds me of Pontryagin, who did amazing work in topology despite being blind. Also, I seem to recall Euler went blind at some point in life. Audiobooks would not be a bad idea!

Comment: Good luck finding an audio book that involves commutative diagrams.

Comment: @DavidWhite those are two very big names. I think maths communication is very attached to classic methods. Probably it will have to evolve a lot before useful advanced audiobooks are produced, I guess.

Comment: A long time ago I had a blind student who had set up his laptop to read raw LaTeX code to him, at very high speed.  Lecturers would give him LaTeX copies of their notes, and he would also type his own notes in LaTeX.  Something like that probably works much better than standard audio for a blind person who is serious about mathematics, although it requires a large initial effort.

Comment: @KConrad, that reminds me of an audiobook I heard, mostly pop sci quantum mechanics, but with a few equations thrown in.  The pop sci was interesting enough that I managed, but with some anguish, to sit through the narrator saying "delta times v divided by delta times t …".

Answer (score 3):

[The Great Courses](https://www.thegreatcourses.com/category/mathematics.html?CFM=mega_menu) has a selection of video courses that include graduate level mathematics, for example this course on [Discrete Mathematics](https://www.thegreatcourses.com/courses/discrete-mathematics.html) or this one on [differential equations,](https://www.thegreatcourses.com/courses/mastering-differential-equations-the-visual-method.html) or one on [number theory.](https://www.thegreatcourses.com/courses/introduction-to-number-theory) These are audio+video, but you might still be able to get useful information out if you only listen to the audio.

Comment: If the audio is sufficiently high quality stereo, in theory one should be able to reconstruct the patterns being drawn on the chalkboard. And those mental computations would make great practice!